Setting Up Dual Boot for Ubuntu 24.04 and Windows 10 with Rufus
I want to use Rufus to create a bootable USB with the Ubuntu 24.04 ISO for a dual-boot setup with Windows 10. My laptop has two disks: Disk 0 (MBR format) contains the C drive, and Disk 1 (GPT format) contains an SSD. Which disk should I shrink to create a partition for Ubuntu? My USB drive is MBR.

Backup your Windows data and convert the MBR drive from BIOS mode to UEFI mode. Then install Ubuntu on the SSD. The Ubuntu installer will automatically select UEFI mode. This way you get both Windows and Ubuntu to be shown as boot options in the same boot menu in the same mode. This is the best way to setup a Windows / Ubuntu dual boot on your laptop. Please comment if you have any reason to object to this way of setting up a dual boot.

If Windows drive is MBR, then it has be be in BIOS boot mode. But Microsoft has required vendors to install Windows in UEFI boot mode on gpt drives since 2012 and release of Windows 8. So is Windows really in BIOS boot mode? Did you upgrade from an old Windows 7 or incorrectly install it in BIOS/MBR mode? If UEFI hardware, better to have both Windows & Ubuntu in UEFI/gpt boot mode. How you boot install media UEFI or BIOS is then how it installs or repairs. For both Windows & Ubuntu.
